# Inner model for KP and a Well-Ordering of the Reals

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory, inner-model-theory, constructibility

It is well known that Gödel proved the following theorem:

- $\mathsf{ZFC + V=L}$ has a $\mathit{\Delta}^1_2$-good well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$. (Gödel, Addison)

So:

- **Is there an inner model for KP/Z/... has a $\mathit{\Delta}^1_1$-good well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$?**
- **Is it possible to reach lower hierarchy?**

Comment: What does "good" mean here?

Comment: @NoahSchweber related to https://mathoverflow.net/q/447047

Comment: The definition of goodness doesn't appear there either ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber The definition itself is a not-so-short story: it can be further divided into boldface and lightface of "${\Delta}^1_n$ well-ordering". See https://mathoverflow.net/a/116465 . If you're just asking what "good" means, deleting it shouldn't hurt...

Comment: The word "good" doesn't appear anywhere in that linked post! Do you just mean "lightface"? I'm familiar with lightface/boldface, but I really don't know what you mean by "good" here. You don't have to give a complete definition, but a link to a place where some definition is given would be great (neither of the links provided does this).

Comment: Does [this](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/11/11/2517) answer your question?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think the paper referenced is [*Addison, J.W. Some consequences of the axiom of constructibility. Fundam. Math. 1959, 46, 337–357*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/j-w-addison-some-consequences-of-the-axiom-of-constructibility-fundamenta-mathematicae-vol-46-1959-pp-337357/A530C2214B80D15C7F8B8990217A526D).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I believe "good $\Delta^1_2$ well ordering" means that not only is the ordering relation $\Delta^1_2$ but there is a $\Delta^1_2$ function mapping each real to a code for its (countable) set of predecessors  in the ordering. I think this is in Moschovakis's "Descriptive Set Theory".  Goodness is used to produce $\Delta^1_2$ things whose production in ZFC would involve choice and thus would be undefinable (e.g., ultrafilters on $\omega$, Hamel bases for $\mathbb R$, Vitali sets).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Re the first question with KP, yes, $L_{\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}}$.
(Use the order of constructibility and Ville's Lemma.)

The second question is a bit vague. But  for each ordinal $\alpha<\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$, the constructibility order on the reals in $J_\alpha$ is a $\Delta_1^{J_\alpha}$-good wellorder, and also a $(\Delta_1^1)^{J_\alpha}$-good wellorder, and one can convert $(\Delta_1^1)^{J_\alpha}$ into a natural bound on complexity strictly within $\Delta^1_1$.

Comment: What is Ville's lemma and why does it produce a $\Delta^1_1$ well-ordering of the reals in $L_{\omega_1^{ck}}$?

Comment: Something along the lines of: if $M$ is a model of enough (but a small fragment of) set theory which has wellfounded $\omega$, then its wellfounded part models KP, and hence $L_{\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}}\subseteq M$. Therefore there is no such $M$ in $L_{\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}}$. So working in $L_{\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}}$, the set of codes $x\in\mathbb{R}$ for levels $L_\alpha$ of $L$ (necessarily with $\alpha<\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$) is $\Delta^1_1$ (i.e. they are the same as the codes for models $M$ with wellfounded $\omega$ which satisfy "$V=L$").

Comment: Thank you! Just for the benefit of my own understanding: in $L_{\omega_1^{ck}}$, a well-ordering of the reals can be defined as "$x\prec y$ iff there is a code of an $\omega$-model of $V=L$ that thinks $x<_L y$" (and $x\not\prec y$ iff $y\prec x$). Ville's lemma is used to ensure that, every $\omega$-model of $V=L$ in $L_{\omega_1^{ck}}$ is actually well-founded, because otherwise their standard part would contain $L_{\omega_1^{ck}}$. Is that the reasoning?

Comment: What I'm slightly unsure about is that the lemma by Ville typically is stated as "if $M$ is an $\omega$-model of $KP$, then so is its standard part." But there are no $\omega$-models of $KP$ in $L_{\omega_1^{ck}}$. Does this mean that, in the assumption of Ville's lemma, $M$ can be assumed to satisfy something weaker than $KP$?

Comment: Right, we can instead require that $M$ models "$V=L$" + some very basic set theory + $\Sigma_0$-separation + "for every $x$ and every $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi$, if $\varphi(x)$ is true then there is a least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha$ models $\varphi(x)$". Any model $M$ of this theory with wellfounded $\omega$ has wellfounded part isomorphic to $L_\beta$ for some ordinal $\beta$ such that $L_\beta$ models KP.